# WideImage - Transparent PNG to JPEG

Tags: php, image

Whenever a user uploads a photo using my script, WideImage converts it to JPEG. However, I just noticed that if I upload a PNG picture, with a transparent background, it makes it black instead.

Is there any way to make this white instead?

This is how i save the image:

```
$img->resizeDown('500', null)->saveToFile('annonce_billeder/'.$bnavn.'.jpeg', 70);
```

Comment: is this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965709/wideimage-transparent-areas-of-converted-png-should-be-white/13427679 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

I looked through the API and I don't see anything for setting the BG color on resizeDown or changing the alpha channel on the PNG before resizeDown... I do however, think that you can use the merge method to merge the PNG with a white background image. Take a look at the API for that function, essentially the PNG image would be the "watermark".

http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/doc/WideImage/WideImage_Image.html#methodmerge

---

Posting some code might help... you might be able to use this method

$white = $image->allocateColor(255, 255, 255);

Comment: I guessed since it was a question concerning the library, my own code would be irrelevant. However, i added it to the post :-)

$img->resizeDown('500', null)->allocateColor(255, 255, 255)->saveToFile('annonce_billeder/'.$bnavn.'.jpeg', 70);
didn't work out