# WideImage - Transparent areas of converted PNG should be white

Tags: php, image

Whenever a user uploads a photo using my script, WideImage converts it to JPEG. However, I just noticed that if I upload a PNG picture, with a transparent background, it makes it black instead.

Is there any way to make this white instead?

This is how i save the image:

```
$img->resizeDown('500', null)->saveToFile('annonce_billeder/'.$bnavn.'.jpeg', 70);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really directly. You wnt to read about how transparency is stored in pictures: it is an ordinary color value (any color) that has been marked especially as transparent.

So most likely the color specified in the example pictures you try actually *is* coded as black and the transparency gets lost whilst converting.

You might have a try to find out if you can detect if there is a color marked as transparent in the incoming picture and then manually change that color to non-transparcy and white before converting the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Might be similar, but I was able to create an empty truecolor image and fill it with its own transparent color before doing any drawing:

```
$img = WideImage_TrueColorImage::create(100, 100);
$img->fill(0,0,$img->getTransparentColor());
// then text, watermark, etc
$img->save('...');
```

I assume you'll do something more like:

```
$img = WideImage::load(<source>);
if( <$img is png> ) {
   $img->fill(0,0, $img->getTransparentColor());
}
$img->resizeDown(500, null)->saveToFile('target.jpg', 70);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it:

```
// Load the original image
$original = WideImage::load("image.png");
$original->resizeDown(1000); // Do whatever resize or crop you need to do

// Create an empty canvas with the original image sizes
$img = WideImage::createTrueColorImage($resized->getWidth(),$resized->getHeight());
$bg = $img->allocateColor(255,255,255);
$img->fill(0,0,$bg);

// Finally merge and do whatever you need...
$img->merge($original)->saveToFile("image.jpg");
```

Comment: Transparent PNG images were appearing with black transparent bits, but this worked a charm for adding a white background to transparent images.

Answer (score 1):

With some changes (corrections) on Ricardo Gamba's solution code, it does the job...

```
// Load the original image
$original = WideImage::load("image.png");
$resized  = $original->resizeDown('500', null); // Do whatever resize or crop you need to do
$original->destroy(); // free some memory (original image not needed any more)

// Create an empty canvas with the resized image sizes
$img = WideImage::createTrueColorImage($resized->getWidth(), $resized->getHeight());
$bg  = $img->allocateColor(255,255,255);
$img->fill(0,0,$bg);

// Finally merge and do whatever you need...
$img->merge($resized)->saveToFile("image.jpg", 70);
```